# Fish script for running commands on remote server

Tags: ssh, fish

If I use a sh script, I get this code.

```
ssh user@host <<-'ENDSSH'
    #command 1
    #command 2
ENDSSH
```

What's the analogue in fish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fish does not have heredocs (see https://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html)

```
echo '#command 1
#command 2' | ssh user@host
```

or

```
set commands \
    "command 1" \
    "command 2"

printf "%s\n" $commands | ssh user@host
```